# I would like some advice on my menu bar on my site

Tags: html, css, menu, margin

I have a simple look that I would like for the menu buttons at the top of my site.

[image]

I have already set this up, however I am using a div for each of the menu links (text) and then using the margin tag to separate them.

It seems to look ok, but I want to keep my code tidy.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Many thanks in advance for any advice.

MY HTML

```
<body>
<div class="mainhome">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="menubutton-leftside" style="margin-right:23px"><h2>home</h2></div>
      <div class="menubutton-leftside" style="margin-right:20px"><h2>about</h2></div>
      <div class="menubutton-leftside" style="margin-right:30px"><h2>portfolio</h2></div>
      <div class="menubutton-leftside" style="margin-right:27px"><h2>contact</h2></div>
        <div class="logo"><img src="images/es-logo.png" width="170" height="170" /></div> 
      <div class="menubutton-rightside" style="margin-left:17px"><h2>print</h2></div>
      <div class="menubutton-rightside" style="margin-left:25px"><h2>digital</h2></div>
      <div class="menubutton-rightside" style="margin-left:38px"><h2>illustration</h2></div>
      <div class="menubutton-rightside" style="margin-left:20px"><h2>brand</h2></div>
  </div>
```

MY CSS

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    background-image:url(images/header-background.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.mainhome {
    width: 855px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.header {
    height: 236px;
    background-image:url(images/header-background.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    clear:left;
}

.mainimage {
    width: 855px;
    height: 423px;
    background-color:#0C9;
    position:absolute;
    top:220px;
    float:left;
    z-index:-1;
}

#slider_container {
        width:855px;
        height:423px;
        overflow:hidden;
}

.bluebar {
    width: 855px;
    height: 16px;
    background-color:#334d5c;
    clear:left;
    float:left;
}

.menubutton-leftside {
    width:60px;
    height:20px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:95px;
}

.menubutton-rightside {
    width:60px;
    height:20px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:95px;
    text-align:right;
}

h2 {
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#666;
    display:inline;
}

.logo {
    width:170px;
    height:170px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:30px;
}

.largemenubutton {
    width:261px;
    height:259px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:20px;
}

.footer {
    width:100%;
    height: 61px;
    background-color:#334d5c;
    clear:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time that you find yourself having to add inline styles, it's time to rethink the approach.  Here's some markup that accomplishes what you want, but it's cleaner and it's easier to follow and maintain.  Here's the [outcome](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/s5qXE/embedded/result/) (without your logo of course).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="mainhome">
    <div class="header">
        <a href="#">home</a>
        <a href="#">about</a>
        <a href="#">portfolio</a>
        <a href="#">contact</a>
        <img src="images/es-logo.png" class="logo" /> 
        <a href="#">print</a>
        <a href="#">digital</a>
        <a href="#">illustration</a>
        <a href="#">brand</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.mainhome {
    width: 850px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
    height: 236px;
    background-image:url(images/header-background.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    clear: both;
}

.header a {
    width: 85px;    
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#666;
    display:block;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:95px;
}

.logo {
    width:170px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:30px;
}

/*other styles copied from your css*/
.mainimage {
    width: 855px;
    height: 423px;
    background-color:#0C9;
    position:absolute;
    top:220px;
    float:left;
    z-index:-1;
}

#slider_container {
    width:855px;
    height:423px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.bluebar {
    width: 855px;
    height: 16px;
    background-color:#334d5c;
}

.largemenubutton {
    width:261px;
    height:259px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:20px;
}

.footer {
    width:100%;
    height: 61px;
    background-color:#334d5c;
    clear:left;
}
```

So, here's what I did:

1. Changed the fixed width of your design to be 850px instead of 855px.  The reason is that this way, when you subtract out your 170px for the logo, you get 680, which is divisble by 8 (the total number of links).  85px also happens to be 1/2 of 170, so it creates a perfectly balanced design.
2. I removed all of the divs and h2 and replaced them with anchor tags (eventually, I assume you will want these to be links, so you might as well just style the links versus having all that extra markup and css).
3. I removed the extra div markup around the image tag and just added the class directly to the img itself.
4. I then floated the all of the anchors tags in the header div (.header a) and .logo classes left.
5. Then it was just a matter of styling the links themselves.  I added your styles for the font family, size, wieght and color, and added text-decoration: none so that the anchor tags wouldn't get any underline.  I also added your top margin here.  To make sure that the links are equally spaced, I set them to display: block, gave them a width of 85 pixels and floated them left.  Lastly, I set them to text-align center.

To make this even more maintainable, you could change the width of the anchors to 10% and the width of the .logo class to 20%.  This will make it easier for you to change the width of the entire design inside media queries, lending itself to a more responsive design in the future when you realize you need that.

(Just a note, I removed the unnecessary styles and just left the ones that weren't relevant to the html you posted.  You'll want to make sure to adjust the width on each of those elements to be 850px now instead of 855px where appropriate.  Better yet, if they are inside your mainhome wrapper, just make them 100%).

Answer (score 0):

In `menubutton-rightside` and `menubutton-rightside` you can add `font-size: 24px;` and `font-weight: bold;` then remove all the `<h2></h2>` tags. (:

I dont see any more things you can change on.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Just a thought though - doesn't it help to use h tags for SEO purposes?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that only works on `H1` tags.. @user3714234

Answer (score 0):

1. .menubutton-leftside and .menubutton-rightside are almost identical - duplication should be removed. use one single class for them like .menubutton .
2. margin-top:95px; is set on each button. I would set padding-top: 95px; on parent div.
3. you override h2 styles what doesn`t look well. I would merge h2 styles in your css with class .menu-button from point #1